# Does Google maps limit access from web browser clients?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I understand that Google will limit or request compensation for the number of Google Maps request from my server.

How does this work if the request is from the user's client via JavaScript?

**EDIT**.  Based on the previous answer (which was later rescinded to reasons unbeknownst to me), I have looked more into Google's documentation, specifically https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat#client.  It appears there is no limit to client side queries.  I don't wish to violate any rules, and hope I understand this correctly.

> When to Use Client-Side Geocoding
>
> The basic answer is "almost always." As geocoding limits are per user
>   session, there is no risk that your application will reach a global
>   limit as your userbase grows. Client-side geocoding will not face a
>   quota limit unless you perform a batch of geocoding requests within a
>   user session. Therefore, running client-side geocoding, you generally
>   don't have to worry about your quota.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API client-side geocoding via Javascript is not quota limited, however it *is* rate limited. Due to this, you'll see an exponential tail-off in the speed of execution of your queries as you push them through the geocoding API. I've specifically run into this problem when attempting to geocode large number of locations on the client side and switched to server side geocoding as a result.

From: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits

*Using client-side Maps API services (JavaScript) in the browser is rate limited per map session.*